# Telegram aiogram. Как ответить на инлайн кнопку (как обработать callback)?

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, callback

У моего бота следующая структура:

```
app
-handlers
--a.py
--keyboards.py
--__init__.py
-__init__.py
config
-bot.ini
bot.py
```

код bot.py

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import BotCommand
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from app.config_reader import load_config
from app.handlers.a import register_handlers_a
    
async def main():
    config = load_config("config/bot.ini")

    bot = Bot(token=config.tg_bot.token)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

    register_handlers_a(dp)
    await dp.start_polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

код a.py

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

import app.handlers.keyboards as kb

class A(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_initial_data = State()
    waiting_for_time = State()
    
async def a_start(message: types.Message):
    txt = "Введите исходные данные"
    await message.answer(txt, reply_markup=kb.inline_kb1)
    await A.waiting_for_initial_data.set()

#@dp.inline_handler(lambda inline_query: True)
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Нажата инлайн кнопка!')


async def a_initial_data_inputted(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    pass


def register_handlers_a(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(a_start, commands="a", state="*")
    dp.register_message_handler(a_initial_data_inputted, state=A.waiting_for_initial_data)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(process_callback_button1, lambda inline_query: True)
```

Как правильно обработать callback и перейти к следующему State?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал

```
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.answer( "text")
    await callback_query.message.answer("text")
```